# Textbox Currency Format Question

Tags: vb6

Hey there! can I ask you how to make a CURRENCY FORMAT n textbox? Like for instance is ***Php###.##***... Thanks loads!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out these links.

http://www.bigresource.com/VB-How-Format-A-Textbox-For-Currency-qotmHSGy5S.html#yb4rePPaZv
http://forum.codecall.net/visual-basic-programming/16690-format-textbox-currency.html

Regards,

Syed Mustehsan Ikram

Comment: I'm not sure a link to a site that scrapes and redisplays content from yet a 3rd site is the best way to give answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the `Format$()` function.  Example:

```
Text1.Text = Format$(value, "$#,##0.00")
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like 
myInt.ToString("C")

So it would be

`total.text = myInt.ToString("C")`

Where my myInt is the number you manipulate. Or you can do:

`total.text = myInt.ToString('$###,###.00')`

You also may want to look at the masked edit control
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa239801

Comment: I'm using VB6.0, and I think **.ToString** isn't supported